# How do I handle error message thrown from SQL to controller.cs

Tags: c#, sql-server, error-handling

I want to check for duplicate username is exist or not.

In my AddNewUser stored procedure

I have used following code

```
DECALRE @error nvarchar(500)
IF EXISTS(SELECT EMAIL FROM [USERSTABLE] WHERE Email= @Email)  
set @error = 'User already exists with email address '+@Email
RAISERROR (@error,16,1);
```

Now I want to catch this error message on UserNameController.cs

```
try
{
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CreateNewUser", connection))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //some parameters
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}

catch(Exception ex)
{throw ex;}
```

Now in `ex` I'm getting that error message.
But how to show it on View? (.cshtml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `View` you need to create control to show the message about error - usually it will be clean or unvisible. If you got an error - put your message abot error in this control and make it visible.

Change your code here

```
catch(Exception ex)
{/*there must be code to show message*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about storing `'ex'` in a `ViewBag / TempData` and then displaying it in View.

P.S: Pardon me if I am wrong, I don't have much knowledge on MVC.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions would be to enable custom errors in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

Once that is done, create a new view named Error.cshtml in Views/Shared:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
    </h2>
    <p>Controller Name: @Model.ControllerName</p>
    <p>Action Name : @Model.ActionName</p>
    <p>Message: @Model.Exception.Message</p>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Now you will see exception message in this custom view when exception is thrown. No need to catch it manually.